# How to construct a Mobius group corresponding to a given fundamental triangle?

Tags: group-theory, mobius-transformation

Most introductory textbooks on the modular group begin with an introduction of it as the group generated by the two Mobius transformations:

$$z'=z+1$$
$$z'=-\frac{1}{z}$$,

and immediately after that, they describe the canonical fundamental domain of the modular group as a certain hyperbolic triangle with angles $\pi/3,\pi/3,0$, which under the action of the modular group tiles up the whole hyperbolic plane. My question refers to the opposite process: given an arbitrary hyperbolic triangle with angles $\pi/n,\pi/m,\pi/l$ (where n,m,l are positive integers), how to construct the generators $T,S$ of the group of Mobius transformation such that this triangle is its fundamental domain?

Comment: Don’t the angles have to satisfy some kind of relations among them, so that there will be some triangles not capable of being a fund. domain? (Not merely that their sum must be less than $\pi$, I mean.)

Comment: What is your definition of a Moebius transformation?? Do you allow reflections/inversions? If you do, simply take the subgroup generated by reflections in the edges of the triangle.